# SharePoint workbench only works for some users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, spfx-webparts, workbench

What exact permissions are required to use the workbench? (`http://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`)

I'm trying to test an SPFx app which involves multiple users. I created some dummy users, and created VMs to simulate multiple people logging in and using the app. The dummy users can get the same code, compile it and use it as normal, but when they try to get to the workbench they get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.

I'm sure that the VM is not to blame, because when I personally log in on the VM it works, and when I change to the dummy user on my local machine it fails in the same way.  I tried upgrading permissions for these dummy users, but so far this has not worked.  I tried scouring the web for exactly what permissions are required to run the workbench, and I have not found anything yet. I appreciate anyone who can tell me the sufficient but not excessive set of permissions/privileges required to run the workbench.

Following is the exact error, which is not helpful to me because I don't know how to get to the `web.config` file for an SPFx app:

```
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```